# How to restrict the props' value of child elements by type of parent element's props in React with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm looking for any ways to restrict the props' value of child elements by the type of parent element's props in React with typescript.

```
type User = { name: string; age: number; };
const Parent = (props: User) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child field="name" /> // ok
      <Child field="age" /> // ok
      <Child field="firstName" /> // not ok
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am look for something like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [Steve's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74301847/157247), but here's an alternative (see inline comments):

```typescript
// The props for `Child`
type ChildProps<FieldNames> = {
    field: FieldNames;
};

// Define a generic type for the Child component.
type ChildType<FieldNames extends string> = (props: ChildProps<FieldNames>) => React.ReactElement;

// Define the component in terms of `string`
const Child: ChildType<string> = (props: ChildProps<string>) => {
    return /*...*/;
};

// Define a refined child that can only use `User` names for `field`
type User = { name: string; age: number };
const ThisChild: ChildType<keyof User & string> = Child;

// Use it
const Parent = (props: User) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ThisChild field="name" /> // ok
            <ThisChild field="age" /> // ok
            <ThisChild field="firstName" /> // not ok
        </div>
    );
};
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-K4MAYO6zh9FCgiAUQfThonrnNTCYrLZeUg0RjQUiyzZsXijDXa2XVF6fcK9WJTPgNQZ8HAqCZdhAA03m3W26M7K5u7akP3BwPaCOx+PW0J2wpp138MEoB0pguh7QQhB4Cvx1iWQ2mzN2UA)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide an explicit generic in that case. Is that what you are looking for?

```
type User = { name: string; age: number };
const Parent = (props: User) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child<User> field="name" /> // ok
      <Child<User> field="age" /> // ok
      <Child<User> field="firstName" /> // not ok
    </div>
  );
};

type ChildProps<T> = {
  field: keyof T;
};

const Child = <T extends unknown>(props: ChildProps<T>) => {
  return null;
};
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgFUBnJKOAXjgG84A7FEEgBccJjCjBeAc1JwUU4XwCuIAEas4AXwpoIvMXAAKKIr3icAFGBxgmI5qwCUHAHzdycOERhKovOBYennAAPAAmwABuLkHBoQDCABbAADZhIQ5QbpjASGns+PyC+HAA9G6lpXAQANaxwSFJqemZ2bn5+PJIJeVlVbX1no3JaRksWXA5eWEFOVBiAHIC3WUVVbwQ8ANxIaUR0UGOFNqUNHRwTWmGNkwhACpunFxBU2kiNUjUEJhwd8cU5F0+nglzCHFCdzgSAAHjAkLwwkw4EpeDUNgB3XguKw3ESg64QWz3FzOdhuZ6eby+fy8JQpFL-IA)